# How to hide and show markers onclick with mapbox gl in a next js project (using react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm currently working on a next js project and using mapbox gl to display some points (markers) on a map. I created buttons to make filters. When the button is clicked, the markers become invisible/hidden. I'm also using Tailwind CSS for the style.

To display the markers, I'm using a geojson file named here as 'geojson'. The following code is only for one type of markers on the map, but the other type of markers are also code like this.

All the code below is inside a useEffect function.

```
// The following code is inside a map.on("load", function())
geojson.features.forEach((marker) => {
        let div = document.createElement('div', {id: 'PV', className: 'visible'});
                
        let point = new mapboxgl.Marker(div).setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates).setPopup(
                        new mapboxgl.Popup({
                            closeButton: false,
                            closeOnClick: false,
                        })
                        .setHTML(`<div id = "hoverPopup">
                            <h4 class="text-[#161616] font-semibold">${marker.properties.Name}</h4>
                            <p class="text-[#161616] text-xs">Adress : ${marker.properties.Adress}</p>
                            </div>`
                        )
                    )

         let rootMarker = createRoot(div);
         rootMarker.render(<Image ref = {ref} id='PV' src={PV} alt="Marker for PV" width={40} height={50} />)

         const markerdiv = point.getElement();
         markerdiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => point.togglePopup());
         markerdiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => point.togglePopup());

         point.addTo(map);
});
```

The following code is to create the filters and the function handleClick() (or onClick) :

```
// This code is inside a map.on("iddle", function())

function handleClick(event) {

                const clickedLayer = event.target.id

                const markers = document.querySelectorAll(`[id='${clickedLayer}']`);

                markers.forEach((marker) => {
                    if (marker.className === 'visible') {
                         marker.className = 'invisible';
                    } else {
                        marker.className = 'visible';
                    }
                });
            };

const link = React.createElement('button', {id:"PV", className: 'text-white flex flex-row items-start', onClick:handleClick}, "PV"); 

const filter = document.getElementById('btn1');
const root = createRoot(filter);
root.render(link);
```

I tried a lot of different things to hide the markers. One of the thing I tried is using a ref and ref.current.classname to change the visibility of the element but it didn't work.

I tried to get the div of the markers by the id to change the classname but it also didn't work.

I think it's a problem with how to get all the markers because one of the thing I tried worked but only for one marker. It was the following function :

```
function handleClick(event) {

                const clickedLayer = event.target.id

                let visibility = ref.current.className;

                if (visibility === 'visible') {
                    ref.current.className = 'invisible';
                } else {
                    ref.current.className = 'visible';
                }
            };
```

I hope that what I want to do was clear. If anyone could help me, let me know :)